# How can I use value_counts() to get a count of values after using a boolean on a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to analyze a data set in colab, and it looks a bit like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('gdrive/My Drive/python_for_data_analysts/Agora Data.csv')
df.info()
```

Data columns (total 9 columns):

```
 #   Column             Non-Null Count   Dtype 
---  ------             --------------   ----- 
 0   Vendor             109689 non-null  object
 1    Category          109689 non-null  object
 2    Item              109687 non-null  object
 3    Item Description  109660 non-null  object
 4    Price             109684 non-null  object
 5    Origin            99807 non-null   object
 6    Destination       60528 non-null   object
 7    Rating            109674 non-null  object
 8    Remarks           12616 non-null   object
```

There's a column of category and origin and what I'm trying to do is get a value count specifically of the categories with an origin of say China or USA only. Something that looks like:

```
df[' Origin'].value_counts().head(30)

USA              33729
UK               10336
Australia         8767
Germany           7876
Netherlands       7707
Canada            5126
EU                4356
China             4185
```

I've filtered out everything other than rows with an origin of China, but when I try to get a value count of the different categories within China, it doesn't output a proper list like the one above.

```
china_transactions = (df[' Origin'] == 'China') & (df[' Category']).value_counts()
china_transactions.head(50)

0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Boolean Series where 'Origin' == 'China' and subset the DataFrame to only those rows. Then take the `value_counts` of the Category column. You can use `DataFrame.loc` to combine row and column selections at once.

```
df.loc[df[' Origin'].eq('China'), 'Category'].value_counts()
#      ------------------------        |            |
#               |                  Take this    apply this
#        Only these rows            column       method
```